# Washer Method to revolve region

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm trying to use the washer method to find volume of solid formed by revolving region bound by $f(x) = 2 - x^2$ and $g(x)= 1$ about the line $y=3$.
So far I have $$V=\int_{-1}^1 \pi(x^4-4x^2+3)dx$$

I don't know if this is correct and am having trouble if anyone can verify the answer it would be great help.
Thank you,
-Henry

Comment: It looks to me as if outer radius is $3-1$, and  inner radius is $3-(2-x^2)=1+x^2$. Area of cross-section $\pi(4-(1+x^2)^2)=\pi(3-2x^2-x^4)$.

Answer (score 0):

The outer radius $R$ for our washer is always equal to 2. The inner radius $r$ is given by $$r=3-(2-x^2)$$

So the volume $v$ of one slice is

$$v=\pi(R^2-r^2)$$
$$=\pi(4-(x^2+1)^2)$$
$$=\pi(3-2x^2-x^4)$$

Now to find the total volume $V$ we integrate the washers from -1 to 1.

$$V=\int_{-1}^1\pi(3-2x^2-x^4)dx$$
$$=2\pi\left[3x-\frac 2 3 x^3-\frac 1 5 x^5\right]_0^1$$
$$=\frac{64\pi}{15}$$